# ROS2 voxel.layer.enabled already declared

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi again,

I have the following [yaml](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ojdSU1hx92PTDYuuWyYsJlsHxqIa_eel/view?usp=sharing) configuration for my navigation. When I launch the navigation with

```
ros2 launch nav2_bringup nav2_navigation_launch.py
```

i get the following error in the moment the transformation from cartographer comes online and the lifecyclemanager starts dwb_controller.

Original error: parameter 'voxel_layer.enabled' has already been declared

I only enable the voxel_layer once in the configuration file, but even removing this line doen't change anything. Is this a known issue ?

Thanks in regards.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/354445/ros2-voxel.layer.enabled-already-declared/) by [Chris91](https://answers.ros.org/users/54232/chris91/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2020-06-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That error is coming from the code calling "declare_parameter" twice - has nothing to do with your configuration file. Most likely this is due to more than one component setting the same parameter without checking if the parameter is already set. I'd suggest filing a bug report on the navigation 2 repo.

It's worth noting that most of the parameters in navigation2 are wrapped in a directive that checks if the parameter is already been declared - [but it looks like this one is not](https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation2/blob/2113b6a7d9a9f8ab2f482047e312a72af87a3b2e/nav2_costmap_2d/plugins/voxel_layer.cpp#L64).

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2020-06-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Chris91](https://answers.ros.org/users/54232/chris91/) on 2020-06-17**:
Thanks i will try opening up a bug report.